# Session variable and Masterpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, master-pages

I want to log a users session on my site. I was hoping to just set a session variable. But the initialisation of it is giving me problems.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["SESSION_GUID"] == null)
    {
        Session["SESSION_GUID"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        return;
    }
    lnkUpload.Visible =  (Session["LOGGED_IN"] != null);
    btnLogout.Visible = (lnkUpload.Visible);
}
```

It seems that the masterpage is creating the variable OK, but the rest of the pages load (ones using that master page). So in my log, I am seeing TWO hits. One with no session ID set, and the second hit has a session id.

Any idea why the child page of this masterpage is loading twice? This only happens on the first request to the site. After that, the session is working fine and we only get one hit.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but aren't you _telling_ it to load twice via the Redirect? The first time the page is called (i.e. pre-Session ID), the session ID gets set and the page is loaded again.

Comment: The code I am showing is in the masterpage - My logic was that when the page loads, it loads the masterpage first (?), and then the actual page that is being requested. On the masterpage's Page_Load, I check the session variable. If its not set, I set it, halt the loading of the called page, and refresh to the called page. So if Page A uses masterpage... I am trying to halt the loading of Page A by the masterpage, set variable, and then load page A. But page A is getting loaded twice. I know I have a refresh, but I thought the refresh would execute before page A is loaded.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I don't think that's the way IIS (or any other web server, for that matter) works. When the page is requested, it's loaded. You could clean things up as best you can by calling Response.ClearContent and/or Response.ClearHeaders, then by calling Response.End, but you're still going to have a log entry indicating that the page was requested twice (because it was).

Comment: @MichaelTodd - actually IIS does handle it quite differently via the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle. There are multiple events that happen sequentially in the request of a page, and processing can be halted throughout the processing pipeline

Comment: @jaywon But will that prevent IIS from writing to a log indicating that the page was requested? I _think_ that's what the OP is basing his question on.

Comment: Sorry guys - I was unclear. I have a custom logging method in my 'Page A' which I was hoping would NOT be loaded if my masterpage stopped the loading. Page_Init has resolved this now.

Comment: @MichaelTodd - no IIS will log the request, but as he said he had custom logging code, so just depends where that is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Page_Load` event of the content page will be called before the `Page_Load` of the master page as seen in steps 6-7 in the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx)

The master page `Page_Init` event is called before the content page `Page_Init` event though, so if all you're doing is checking for Session, probably best to handle it in the `Page_Init` of the master page and redirect there. This could cause problems based on how other code in your project looks but conceptually, one of the first things you are wanting to do is check Session and handle properly so, you don't need page/controls to load before handling the redirect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868670/why-is-the-set-variable-of-a-masterpage-empty-accessing-from-content-page Can you please assist

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a Response.End() in the master page. This will halt the remaining markup from being rendered.