# Why is the set variable of a MasterPage empty accessing from Content Page

Tags: c#

MasterPage:

```
public string strP;

public void Page_Load()
{
    strP = @"SELECT * FROM ...";
}
```

Content Page:

```
public void Page_Load() {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        string strO = Master.strP; //strO = null
    }
}
```

I know I am supposed to use the `Page_Init` but can someone assist me in ensuring I am able to get the set value of `strP` from the content page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others have the same questions or would like to know how to achieve what I requested, here is the detailed steps:

First assign the public variables in the MasterPage:

```
public string strO;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strO = @""; //whatever the variable supposed to be
}
```

Call in Content Page:

```
public string strOT;
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strOT = Master.strO;
}
```

Comment: So that is what I proposed, right? It is either `Init` or the constructor.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to add an example for anyone having the same question.

Answer (score 3):

This is down to the page lifecycle...

The Content Page's load method will fire BEFORE the Masterpage's Load method. Slap a breakpoint in both Load event handlers and you'll see what I mean...

Comment: Sorry Patrick - I read your comment as accusing me of trying to leach off your post. This would be because a) I'm an idiot, and b) I'm ready to kill because I'm trying to debug clientside script on IE and it's all going rather less than perfectly right now...

Answer (score 1):

The `Page_Load()` is meant for you to do some things related to the page. You postpone some things you can't do in the constructor for the relevant objects missing (like the `Request`, `Response`, etc).

Looking at your code, setting a static SQL statement, which doesn't require any interaction with the request, etc. can be done in the constructor already.

If it is related to the request, you could put that in the `Init` event of the master page.

Also see my related answer on [Variables from Master Page always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29345180/993547).

Comment: Why not just VTC as a dupe of your other answer?

Comment: Since he asked for clarification on the related answer.

Comment: I am accessing the variable from multiple pages hence trying to keep it in Master.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: So I said you could, and I even pointed you to the correct event, right?